# What language/technology uses the syntax <%VARIABLE%> and how is it used?

Tags: javascript, java, json, node.js, angular

Ok, let me start this off by saying I'm not a programmer, so this may be a dumb question. Also, based on my searching it looks like ASP uses this syntax but that is NOT what is being used here.

I'm currently digging into a web application and trying to understand how it's working on the back end. In one POST request it takes a parameter named "CATEGORY" and returns some information about that category. If the CATEGORY parameter value is invalid or not found, it returns the error "<%CATEGORY%> is not valid".

I'm trying to figure out how the CATEGORY parameter value is being used on the server side and what technology is processing it. Does being in the angle bracket percent sign tags mean it's just a variable or is it somehow evaluating that input?

As far as I can tell the application is using Java on the backend, with Nodejs and Angularjs.

Here's an example request:

```
POST /lookup HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.123
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

{"CATEGORY":"test123"}
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: close

{"error":"<%CATEGORY%> is not valid."}
```

I've tried searching a lot for answers, but it's a hard thing to search for. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the server side code?  My initial guess would be that this was an hard coded error string.

Comment: I don't at this time, though it's possible that it was hard coded. However, this is the only error in the entire app that I've found with this particular syntax, so it stood out. All of  the other errors are just regular strings - no <%%>.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some [ejs](http://ejs.co/). It's probably used to generate the response with a template.